# WFS Layer - capabilities document contained no layers

Tags: wfs, download, services

I use Quantum GIS 1.8.0 on Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit.  I have problem with WFS Layer. I tried tree WFS:

1) Download services - Parcels (Czech Republic) http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

2) Geonames (Czech Republic) http://geoportal.cuzk.cz/WFS_GN/WFService.aspx?SID=27082012_03561414729376000_PM_021892838861&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

3) Example [geoserv.weichand.de:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities](http://geoserv.weichand.de:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities)

Example #3 is OK.

Example #2 shows Error "The layer geoportal.cuzk.cz/WFS_GN/WFService.aspx?SID=27082012_03561414729376000_PM_021892838861&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=gmgml:GEONAMES&SRSNAME=EPSG:102067 is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map"

Example #1 shows Error "capabilities document contained no layers."

I don't know, where are the differences between services. Could you help me?

Thanks Petr

Answer (score 2):

The two that fail appear to be WFS 2.0 servers so it may be that the default QGIS WFS client can't handle that version - try the [WFS 2.0 client plugin](http://www.weichand.de/2012/06/07/wfs-2-0-client-plugin-for-qgis-english/) and see if that helps.

Comment: Example 3 also appears to be WFS 2.0, but it does have earlier "AcceptVersion" for 1.0.0. The 2.2.0 was new to me...

Answer (score 1):

Example #2 is a protected service. You have to add an additional parameter (in this case "sid") to the request for authorisation. The WFS 2.0 Plugin already supports standard HTTP-Auth (username, password). I will add support for this type of protection in one of the next releases.

Update:

The new version 0.8.2 is online. 
Now you are able to use the protected WFS 2.0 (Geonames (Czech Republic))

1. Add a custom SRS to QGIS (EPSG:102067 is non official and the only SRS which is supported by the WFS)
   http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2012-February/018081.html
2. Use the following URL (WFS 2.0 Client): http://geoportal.cuzk.cz:80/WFS_GN/service.svc/soap?sid=27082012_03561414729376000_PM_021892838861
3. Overwrite the SRS (WFS 2.0 Client): EPSG:0 --> EPSG:102067